# Django Rest Framework. added new list element to request.data, but getting the new element as a nested list

Tags: python, django, list, django-rest-framework

I am building a small Django Rest Framework API with APIView.
It generates a post with tags that are gotten from the DB, but if there are no tags or I want to add a new tag, a list of tag names is passed into the payload and creates them along with the post, then the new tag IDs are added to the request.data['tags'].

These are the Models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-title']
```

These are the Serializers:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for Tag get model """
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for Post create, update, delete model """
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'description', 'publish', 'tags')
```

This is the payload I am passing for new tags:

```
{
    'title': 'Test Creating with new tags',
    'new_tags': ['newest', 'newer']
}
```

This is the post method:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    """ Creates a Post instance """
    if isinstance(request.data, QueryDict):
        request.data._mutable = True

    tmp_new_tags = request.data.get('new_tags', None)
    if tmp_new_tags:
        new_tags = request.data.pop('new_tags')
        request.data.update({'tags': []})
        for new_tag in new_tags:
            tag = Tag.objects.create(name=new_tag, user=self.request.user)
            request.data['tags'].append(str(tag.id))

    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is the request.data with existing tags that I am expecting for new tags:

```
<QueryDict: {'title': ['Test Creating'], 'tags': ['1', '2']}>
```

But I got the tags in a nested list,

```
<QueryDict: {'title': ['Test Creating with new tags'], 'tags': [['3', '4']]}>
```

This is the response.data:

```
{'tags': [ErrorDetail(string="“['3', '4']” is not a valid UUID.", code='invalid')]}
```

**How can I append a List(1D) instead of nested list to *request.data['tags']*?**

Comment: Share your serializers and the models

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you just have to create a new list and append values to it.
and then call setlist() method to set the list to your request.data.
for example:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    """ Creates a Post instance """
    if isinstance(request.data, QueryDict):
        request.data._mutable = True

    tmp_new_tags = request.data.pop('new_tags')
    if tmp_new_tags:
        tag_list = []
        for new_tag in temp_new_tags:
            tag = Tag.objects.create(name=new_tag, user=self.request.user)
            tag_list.append(tag.id)
        request.data.setlist('tags', tag_list)

    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please do not alter `_mutable` unless extremely needed, it is private attribute (starts with underscore). You'd better use `data = request.data.copy()` and use `data` instead of `request.data` later. It is immutable by design.